# I am trying to make an URL shortener and I am facing this problem

Tags: python-3.x, tinyurl

This is the python code:

```
import pyshorteners as p
    
link=input("Enter the link: ")
shortner=p.tinyurl.short(link)
x=shortner.tinyurl.short(link)

print(x)
```

This is the error:
`module 'pyshorteners' has no attribute 'tinyurl'`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```py
shortner=p.tinyurl.short(link)
```

with

```py
shortner=p.Shortener()
```

Taken from the example here: https://pyshorteners.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

That's because `pyshorteners` doesn't have an attribute `tinyurl` Try using the example from the documentation (https://pyshorteners.readthedocs.io/en/latest/apis.html#tinyurl-com) instead

```
import pyshorteners
s = pyshorteners.Shortener()
s.tinyurl.short('http://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use Shortener() from the pyshorteners. To solve this problem you can use the code below:

```
from pyshorteners import *

print(Shortener().tinyurl.short('http://www.google.com'))
```